# Notification.Builder не принимает this

Tags: java, android, уведомления

`Notification.Builder(this)`, не работает выдает ошибку. Этот метод находится не в классе `MainActivity`, поэтому не использую `MainActivity.this`. Пробовал `Service.this(`Метод находится в классе `Service`) и `android.content.Context` и `getApplicationContext()`, ничего из перечисленного не работает

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)// Не работает здесь
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_cc397d54c2161005908a3034c5fabbea)
    .setContentTitle("Notify")
    .setContentText("Some text")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: В сервисе Notification.Builder(this) должно работать. Если нет - покажите класс целиком

Comment: Но ниже всё-таки используется `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Да, поменять забыл, но и там тоже this не работал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случаи я сам тупанул, т.к я создал этот метов в простом классе, а нужно было в сервисе(службе), и this прекрасно заработал

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил ваше метод у себя и там this подставляется без каких-либо проблем если класс в котором это вызывается является `Activity` или `Service`(в целом, любой класс, наследующийся от `Context`).

Отсюда вывод: "В вашем случае `this` не является `Context-ом`", другого быть не может.

Что может быть? Либо вы где-то ошиблись с наследованием в самой активити/сервисе, либо вы используете билдер внутри какой-то лямбды или анонимной функции или может быть внутреннем классе, может быть что-то еще упустил. Но проблема однозначно в том, что `this` - это не контекст.

Ну либо второй вариант (хотя это очень вряд-ли в вашем случае) вы что-то не то импортировали и это не та функция.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я уже сам разобраться